# Unexpected keyword error with lmplot inside a FacetGrid

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm getting a strange error when trying to use `lmplot` inside a `FacetGrid`.

My code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, col='time', row='sex')
g.map(sns.lmplot, 'total_bill', 'tip')
```

I'm getting :

> TypeError: lmplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `lmplot()` already comes with `FacetGrid` (it is a combination of `regplot` and `FacetGrid`, see doc https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html#seaborn.lmplot), so when you're calling it, those two clash. If you want to plot what you're asking, just call `regplot()` within the `FacetGrid`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, col='time', row='sex')
g.map(sns.regplot, 'total_bill', 'tip')
```

[image: Regplot+FacetGrid]

If you insist on `lmplot()`, you can use the following snippet:

```py
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", row="sex", col="time", data=tips)
```

[image: lmplot]